# Stomp 1.1 Fuse Message Broker 5.5

Tags: stomp

Does Apache Fuse 5.5 supports stomp 1.1 completely?

I am trying to send "NACK" from python client. The connection is made on version 1.1

```
##############Connected##########
{'body': '', 'headers': {'session': 'ID:ap-pun-ws6099-60937-1327039578399-2:5',
'version': '1.1', 'server': 'ActiveMQ/5.5.1-fuse-01-13', 'heart-beat': '1000,100
0'}, 'cmd': 'CONNECTED'}
```

but when i send "NACK" it throws exception saying `2012-01-20 13:46:03,815 receiver ERROR Received server error - messageNACK received but connection is in v1.0 mode`.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

A bug was found for this and resolved today: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3670